# Using events from StencilJS in ReactJS using React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, stenciljs

Has anyone managed to find a way for using custom events created in StencilJS in ReactJS using React useRef() and useEffect() hooks?

I have looked at the StencilJS documentation for this they only cover this for arrays and custom objects.

I am new to front-end development, so any help would be a step in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure React doesn't support custom events, so afaik you'll need to use `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` to attach regular event listeners to the DOM.

Comment: I understand, I am however trying to create the event listeners using the useRef() and useEffect() hooks in React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue for my functional component using the useRef() and useEffect() React hooks, with guidance from [this article](https://linguinecode.com/post/when-to-use-useref-and-uselayouteffect), as seen below:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const Form = () => {
    const [ name, setName ] = useState('');
    const nameInputField = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const { current } = nameInputField;

        //First parameter is the name of the event in Stencil component
        //Second parameter is the custom function
        current.addEventListener('onChanged', () => setName('Steph'););

        //Component is unmounting so removing the event listener
        return () => current.removeEventListener('onChanged', () => setName('Steph'););
    }, []);

    return (
        <stencil-component-with-event 
            ref={nameInputField} 
            value={name} 
            type='text' 
        />
    )
}
```

I hope this makes sense:)

Comment: Yeah that makes sense (I guess it's the functional equivalent of using the lifecycle hooks), but you can't remove the event listener like that... two functions are not equal just because they have the same implementation. You'll have to store a reference of your function somewhere.

Comment: how to handle if there are multiple stencil components with events inside the render @HeediBoy

Comment: @VishnuShenoy you would have to create a reference for each of those components using the useRef React hook in a functional component. In the example above I created the nameInputField ref and attached the ref to the Stencil Component.